# How i can get STPPaymentMethodCardParams from STPPaymentMethod . IOS. Stripe

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

Im lerning objective-c and IOS and i want to create app with a payment. So i have callback method with a cart result

```
-(void) addCardViewController:(STPAddCardViewController *)addCardViewController
                                            didCreatePaymentMethod:(STPPaymentMethod *)paymentMethod
                                            completion:(STPErrorBlock)completion {
    ....
    stpPaymentMethod = paymentMethod;

...
}
```

This method is return `STPPaymentMethod` object. Then i want get card data and create payment like this

```
     //i need replace this line to my STPPaymentMethod <- get card params from this
    //STPPaymentMethodCardParams *cardParams = self.cardTextField.cardParams; 
        //something like this
 STPPaymentMethodCardParams *cardParams = stpPaymentMethod.card
        STPPaymentMethodParams *paymentMethodParams = [STPPaymentMethodParams paramsWithCard:cardParams billingDetails:nil metadata:nil];
        STPPaymentIntentParams *paymentIntentParams = [[STPPaymentIntentParams alloc] initWithClientSecret:self.paymentIntentClientSecret];
        paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams;
```

But i have an error from stripe `Payment failed Invalid object`. So how i can get `STPPaymentMethodCardParams` from `STPPaymentMethod` ?

Comment: Hmm. `STPPaymentMethodCardParams` is only used to _create_ a STPPAymentMethod. But you don't need to do that, you -already have one_, you got it from the `didCreatePaymentMethod` delegate function. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: for example if you're trying to get the details of the credit card from the STPPaymentMethod, it's this : `if(stpPaymentMethod.type == STPPaymentMethodType.typeCard) {print(stpPaymentMethod.card.last4) }`  (from https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentMethod.html#/c:objc(cs)STPPaymentMethod(py)card)